# How to detect a mouseButtonPressed event outside a QGraphicsView widget?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qgraphicsview

I have a QGraphicsView widget with a QGraphicsScene set in it. I wish to detect a mouseButtonPressed event anywhere in my application window **outside** of the QGraphicsView widget.

I tried to install an eventFilter to the central widget of the application as follows:

```
self.centralwidget.installEventFilter(self)
```

My QGraphicsView widget is self.viewStartImg. In my eventFilter method, I have the following:

```
def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
    if obj != self.viewStartImg and event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
            print('Outside the QGraphicsView')
```

In my application, when I click inside of the QGraphicsView, I still get 'Outside the QGraphicsView' printed out. I believe that's happening because QGraphicsView is a child of the centralWidget, but I am not sure.

Any alternate method of achieving this functionality is highly appreciated!

Comment: provide a [mre]

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to achieve this. One way would be to subclass `QGraphicsView` and override `mousePressEvent` in the subclass. Another possibility is to install an event filter on the view object. For the first method you would do something like this

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore

class MyView(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print('mouse pressed inside view')
        event.accept()

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.central = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.view = MyView(self.central)
        self.scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
        self.view.setScene(self.scene)

        hlayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.central)
        hlayout.setContentsMargins(50,50,50,50)
        hlayout.addWidget(self.view)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.central)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print('mouse pressed ouside view')
        event.accept()

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    win = MyWindow()
    win.show()
    app.exec()
```

And for the second one

```
class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    money_changed = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.central = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.view = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self.central)
        self.scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
        self.view.setScene(self.scene)

        hlayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.central)
        hlayout.setContentsMargins(50,50,50,50)
        hlayout.addWidget(self.view)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.central)

        self.view.installEventFilter(self)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print('mouse pressed ouside view')
        event.accept()

    def eventFilter(self, object, event):
        if object == self.view and event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
            print('mouse pressed inside view')
            return True
        return super().eventFilter(object, event)
```

Answer (score 0):

It may not be exactly what you're looking for, but I recently needed to register when the user clicked outside my widget and used this method:

```
def event(self, event):
    
    if event == None:
        return False

    if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.WindowDeactivate:
        print "Clicked outside"
        self.main_widget.close()

    return super(_ComboBoxPlusDialog, self).event(event)
```

I used this to close the window, as you can see. So it only registers the outside click once. I used this to get around an issue with Qt.Popup disabling input for the IME.